# Reposition custom UIBarbuttonItems in a UIToolbar

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

So I have a `UIToolbar` which has a custom height (which I set by overriding `UIToolbar`'s `-sizeThatFits`.  I want to position my `UIBarButtonItems` higher in the tool bar.  I do so by overriding `-layoutSuviews` as such:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for(UIBarButtonItem* item in self.items)
    {

        UIView *view;
        @try {
            view = [item valueForKey:@"view"];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {    NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);  }

        view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height-33);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for bar buttons made with `-initWithBarButtonSystemItem:`, however it has no effect on bar buttons that I've made with `-initWithCustomView:` or `-initWithTitle:`.

Should I be using something different in `[item valueForKey:@"view"]`, or is there a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out a sublime answer to this question.  I solved my needs by adding switches, etc to custom bar button item.